# SharePoint GetListItems not working

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to get a list of items from a SharePoint list, but when function won't return anything.

Here's my function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    GetList();
    console.log("Ts");
});

function GetList() {
    $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite(
    {                     
        operation : "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName : "ESA Mailing Group Subscribers",                      
        CAMLViewFields : "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Mailing Group Address' />" +"</ViewFields>", 
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'></Eq></Where><OrderyBy><FieldRef Name='MailingAddressGroup'/></OrderBy></Query>",
        completefunc   : function (xData, Status)
            {
                console.log("Dat");
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var liHtml = "<tr><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</td><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_MailingGroupAddress") + "</td></tr>";
                    $("#groupList").append(liHtml); 
                    alert($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                });
            }

    }); 
}
```

There are no errors, except for:
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Is there a way for me to see what's not working in this call?

Comment: which sharepoint version are you using ? SP 2010 or 2013 or online ?

Comment: 2013 version of sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you need to modify.

1) Its recommended to use jQuery 1.11.x with SP Services. So, please change it to use this jQuery library

2) SPGetCurrentSite is used to fetch the current site whereas you need to fetch the items from a sharepoint list. For that, you need to use `GetListItems` method

3) You need to use the internal name of the field in the ViewFields not display name.

4) Your CAML query is incorrect, for now i have removed the `Where` clause as you are not filtering it. Have simply changed it to fetch ordered data.

Try and modify the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    GetList();
    console.log("Ts");
});

function GetList() {
    $().SPServices({                     
        operation : "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName : "ESA Mailing Group Subscribers",                      
        CAMLViewFields : "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>", 
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderyBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy></Query>",
        completefunc : function (xData, Status){
                console.log("Dat");
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var liHtml = "<tr><td>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</td></tr>";
                    $("#groupList").append(liHtml); 
                    alert($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
                });
            }
        }); 
}
```

Not really sure why SPServices is not working, however in 2013 we have access to REST API endpoints. So, you can also try using the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    GetList();
    console.log("Ts");
});

function GetList(){
    $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ESA Mailing Group Subscribers')/items?$orderby=Title asc",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {            
                for(var i=0;i < data.d.results.length;i++){
                    var liHtml = "<tr><td>" + data.d.results[i].Title + "</td></tr>";
                    $("#groupList").append(liHtml); 
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Now I get "POST https://intra.sdc.gov.on.ca/sites/cac-maple/collab/esa/team/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx 400 (Bad Request)"

Comment: Please check edited code. Also ensure that you are using the correct internal name of  `MailingAddressGroup` column.

Comment: Yes, used your code but that error for lists.asmx bad request keeps coming. Don't know what that is?

Comment: are you using i from the current site ? Also ensure that you are using the correct list name and internal column names.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it from a current site. That's why I had put in SPGetCurrentSite. When I put that in, I don't get that error anymore.

Comment: Can you check this different approach ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: _spPageContextInfo is not defined

Comment: Replace that sppagecontextinfo.webabsoluteurl with your site url inside double quotes.